# Are there performance reasons to not run a sql database client side

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs, sqlite, react-redux

Recently I've been reading the docs for Redux, and in the [Updating Normalized Data](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UpdatingNormalizedData.html#redux-orm) section it mentions that you might want to use [Redux ORM](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm). After playing around with it, I found myself prepared to write the database equivalents of "ON CASCADE DELETE" and "DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP".

Then I found JavaScript sqlite libraries like [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) and [better-sqlite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3). I assume that they are intended for server-side JavaScript, but I wanted to know if there are performance reasons to not run sqlite client side. I figure that Inserts/Selects/Deletes will be optimized, and I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel for any database features, but maybe indexing and creating tables is slow?

Comment: Well client side data would always be a cache. You would have to synchronize it at some point. Unless you domain involves working with temporary data. There are also hard size limits to `localStorage` and whatnot that vary by platform.

Comment: The data I'd be working with is saved on a back end server, and it only needs to persist client side as long as the user is on the website. Also even if I stored the data in variables instead of a JS database I would still have to deal with synchronization right?

Comment: Right. Those some limitations apply to running anything on the client, including an SQL database implementation.